# como pintar uma data vencida com css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

tenho um table que mostra os vencimentos, como posso deixar a fonte vermelha ou o fundo vermelho se estiver vencido?  usando css

minha table é montada da seguinte forma

```
 <table id="myTable" class="uk-table sortable uk-table-hover uk-text-nowrap" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" width="99%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="uk-width-1-10 uk-text-center small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-change="sellall()" ng-model="table1.selectAll" class="check_all" table-check-all></th>
                                    <th style="width: 80px">AÇÕES</th>
                                    <th style="width: 70px">EMISSÃO</th>
                                    <th style="width: 70px">VENCIMENTO</th>
                                    <th style="width: 200px">PESSOA</th>
                                    <th style="width: 80px; text-align:right">VALOR</th>
                                    <th style="width: 80px; text-align:right">PAGO</th>
                                    <th style="width: 80px; text-align:right">SALDO</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Selecionado:<span class="uk-badge uk-badge-notification uk-text-large">{{valSelecionado | currency : ''}}</span></th>
                                    <th>Pago: <span class="uk-badge uk-badge-notification uk-badge-success uk-text-large">{{valJaPago | currency : ''}}</span></th>
                                    <th>Saldo: <span class="uk-badge uk-badge-notification uk-badge-warning uk-text-large">{{valBaixar | currency : ''}}</span></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th style="text-align:right">{{totalSelect | currency: ''}}</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:right">{{totalPago | currency: ''}}</th>
                                    <th style="text-align:right">{{totalSelect - totalPago| currency: ''}}</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                            <tbody>
                                <!--ng-change="tteste()" ng-checked="tteste()" ng-click="tteste()"-->
                                <tr ng-repeat="item in registro" on-last-repeat>
                                    <td class="uk-text-center uk-table-middle small_col"><input type="checkbox" icheck ng-model="tabela[$index]" ng-change="addRem($index, tabela, item)" class="check_row" table-check-row></td>
                                    <td style="width: 50px" class="">
                                        <a class="tooltip" title="Deletar" ng-click="delRegistro(item)"><i class="md-icon material-icons uk-text-danger tooltip" title="Deletar">&#xE872;</i></a>
                                        <a ng-click="editRegistro(item)" href="#modalcadastro" data-uk-modal="{ center:true, bgclose:false }"><i class="md-icon material-icons tooltip" title="Editar">mode_edit</i></a>
                                        <a ng-click="setDadosBaixar(item)" href="#modalbaixa" data-uk-modal="{ center:true, bgclose:true }"><i class="md-icon material-icons tooltip" title="Editar">file_download</i></a>
                                        <a ng-click="cleanContaMov(); getContaMov(item)" href="#modalbaixados" data-uk-modal="{ center:true, bgclose:true }"><i class="md-icon material-icons tooltip" title="Visualizar baixas parciais">chrome_reader_mode</i></a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{item.dt_emissao}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.dt_vencto}}</td>
                                    <td>{{item.PessoaModel.razao | limitTo : 30 : 0}} <a ng-if="item.PessoaModel.razao.length > 30">...</a> </td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right">{{item.valor | currency: ''}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right">{{item.vlr_pago | currency: ''}}</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:right">{{item.saldo | currency: ''}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

*** tenho um campo que quando esta vencido o valor dele é "sim"

Comment: O ideal será aplicar um estilo no momento que a tabela estiver sendo montada, para não precisar percorrer toda ela depois. Ela é carregada por ajax? Compartilhe conosco os trechos relevantes de código de como a tabela é criada.

Comment: Com html e css não tem como verificar, você precisa usar javascript. Coloque as tags adequadas na sua pergunta.

Comment: você não pode usar `js`??

Comment: eu uso angular, carrego a table usando ng-repeat com o json que vem do backend, poderia uasr js sim **Nao axei opção de editar o post

Comment: `class="dt-vencida-color"` já existia antes da resposta do Mateus ser dada?

Comment: nao, esqueci de tirar, nao funcionou, pois nao valida a data

Comment: Você disse que possui um campo que armazena se a data está vencida ou não. Que campo é esse?

Comment: sim, é um campo que vem do back com o valor "sim" ou "nao" para vencido, poderia usar ele para definir a cor, só nao sei como usar, se uso com ng-show, ou ng-if, ou por css

Comment: Use o `ng-class` para adicionar a classe CSS se o valor deste campo for sim.

Comment: @alessandremartins É possível para você adicionar uma classe nesta linha? `<td>{{item.dt_vencto}}</td>`. Se sim, minha resposta irá validar e funcionar.

Comment: é sim Leon, vou testar, para usar o ng-class, vou precisar usar tb o ng-if ?

Comment: @alessandremartins Da forma que fiz o meu exemplo, você precisa seguir apenas o que está lá. O uso do `datejs` é importante para poder validar as datas, apenas.

Comment: @LeonFreire, não deu certo, estou usando um template admin, se nao importar o date e o jquery nao funciona, mas quando importo, da um monte de conflito.

Comment: @alessandremartins Hmmm... Da parte de conflitos, eu teria que ver como foi instalado e o que pode estar conflitando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando Angular, então use-o para implementar a lógica necessária. Você disse que possui uma coluna que tem valor Sim/Não indicando se a data está vencida, então basta você adicionar uma classe CSS ao elemento que possuir essa coluna igual a sim. No elemento, adicione:

```
ng-class="{'dt-vencida': item.vencido=='sim'}"
```

Se o valor de `vencido` for `"sim"`, então a classe `dt-vencida` é adicionada ao elemento. No CSS, defina a classe com `color: red`, por exemplo.

Veja um exemplo funcional abaixo:

```js
angular
  .module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function myController($scope) {
  $scope.itens = [
    {name: "Item 1", vencido: "não"},
    {name: "Item 2", vencido: "sim"},
    {name: "Item 3", vencido: "não"}
  ];
}
```

```css
.dt-vencida {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <li ng-repeat="item in itens">
    <span ng-class="{'dt-vencida': item.vencido=='sim'}">{{item.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Apenas o item 2 da lista possui o valor `vencido='sim'`, então somente ele possuirá a classe `dt-vencida` e, portanto, só ele ficará na cor vermelha.

Comment: Com esse exemplo, ele valida a data ou só funciona se ele tiver previamente definido se está expirado ou não?

Comment: @LeonFreire Deve estar pré-definido. Como o autor disse que tal valor existe, é possível considerar que a validação é feita no servidor.

Comment: Entendi. Então no caso do angular, existira essa validação sendo feita já pelo servidor e esse código iria capturar essa validação e inserir a classe? Vou ter que estudar esse Angular.

Comment: @LeonFreire Angular é só *front-end*. A lista de itens ali eu criei manualmente a fim de exemplificar, mas o valor de `$scope.itens` seria o retorno de uma requisição AJAX, por exemplo. O servidor, independente da linguagem, irá fazer a validação e definir o valor de `vencido` como `sim`, se estiver vencido, ou `não`. A cláusula `ng-class` do Angular apenas permite você adicionar uma classe ao elemento se determinada condição for satisfeita. Neste exemplo, a classe `dt-vencida` é adicionada se a condição `item.vencido=='sim'` for satisfeita.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, resolvido, angular é mágico, pra quem sabe usar. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Segue um exemplo utilizando classes.

```css
.dt-vencida-color{
  color: red;
}

.dt-vencida-background{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mateus</td>
      <td class="dt-vencida-color">25/06/2017</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mateus</td>
      <td class="dt-vencida-background">25/06/2017</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Não responde a pergunta. O objetivo é checar se está vencido para aplicar o estilo.

Comment: Você leu direitinho a pergunta ? ele nao pediu uma função para verificar se a data está vencida ou não.

Comment: Até porque não tem nem informação de quando a data vai estar vencida ou como a tabela é alimentada

Comment: **se** *estiver vencido*. Pra isso temos a área de comentários. Se a dúvida fosse de como aplicar um estilo qualquer, provavelmente será duplicada.

Comment: A dúvida é como aplicar o estilo, 'como pintar uma data vencida com css'

Comment: Já leu sobre votos negativos ? Antes de votar poderia ter comentado antes. Até a próxima

Comment: E como o código vai saber que a data está vencida? Não é pessoal @MateusVeloso, é ético explicar o motivo de um voto negativo. Responder apenas com base no título sem usar comentários deixa sujeito à isso, é minha opinião.

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo fielmente apenas a informação que você passou (suas opções ficaram meio em aberto), acredito que você possa adaptar o `datejs` ao seu site.

Retire dos exemplos as informações mais importantes. Para seu **HTML**, adicione:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
```

e adiciona a classa `data` onde informei.

Utilize o **JS**:

```
var dia = Date.today();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data').each(function() {
    var dueDate = $(this).text();
    var due = Date.parse(dueDate);
    var compare = Date.compare(due, dia);

    if (compare == -1) {
      $(this).addClass("expirado");
    }
  });
});
```

E por fim o **CSS**:

```
table {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: aliceblue;
}

table td {
  width: 10%;
}

.expirado {
  color: red;
}
```

### EDIT:

Vi que editou a pergunta e agora mostra a sua tabela. O meu exemplo abaixo funciona apenas se a `<td>` com a data de vencimento tiver a class `data` que eu sugeriria que adicionasse. Isso é possível? No caso de não ser, substitua o `.data` por `td:nth-child(2)` e veja se te atende. No seu caso específico, você também pode utilizar ele assim de forma mais completa: `table#myTable tr > td:nth-child(2)`

---

**Deixo abaixo um exemplo que criei usando o Datejs:**

**Exemplo:**

Com `.data`

```js
var dia = Date.today();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.data').each(function() {
    var dueDate = $(this).text();
    var due = Date.parse(dueDate);
    var compare = Date.compare(due, dia);

    if (compare == -1) {
      $(this).addClass("expirado");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background: aliceblue;
}

table td {
  width: 10%;
}

.expirado {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datejs/1.0/date.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">14/06/2017</td>
      <td>ADEMIR</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">30/06/2017</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 1</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">01/01/2017</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 2</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">02/01/2018</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 3</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">15/07/2017</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 4</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">28/02/2012</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 5</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>28/06/2017</td>
      <td class="data">23/05/2020</td>
      <td>EXEMPLO 6</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
      <td>0,00</td>
      <td>500,00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Por quê não usar o Angular direto para implementar a lógica? Bem mais simples, não?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss De repente é mais simples pra quem entende de Angular, que não é meu caso. Hahaha...